# PHP Local host running errors

Tags: php

i want to redirect index.php which if user click on logout button it redirects to login.php page but it don't.
http://localhost:/dropedit/GAMEBOX
and if some one type  like following it went all wrong like,whole page becomes garbled 
http://localhost:/dropedit/GAMEBOX/index.php
logout button code is  Logout ?

i tried but din't find some thing!

Comment: We cannot see your localhost, you need to post the code here and explain better what the problem is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make the login button a part of a form, and have the form submit to index.php. The form will contain an empty input that tells the page that you have been logged out.  For example:

```
<form action = '/' method = 'post'>
  <input style = 'display: none;' name = 'logout' value = 'logoutTrue">
  <input type = 'submit' value = 'Logout'>
</form>
```

Next, a simple if statement to check if you have been logged out:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
  $logoutVal = $_POST['logout'];
  if ($logoutVal === "logoutTrue") {
    header("Location: http://localhost/login.php");
  }
}
?>
```

Uh, this should work, I think? If it doesn't please post the error codes.